# Discord.py banning user not working if DM's disabled

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've got this code for my discord bot, which can ban people and DM them the reason for the ban first.

```
cooldown = []

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_role('Senior Moderator')
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
    author = str(ctx.author)
    if author in cooldown:
        await ctx.send('Calm down! You\'ve already banned someone less than two hours ago.')
        return

    try:
        if reason == None:
            reason = 'breaking the rules.'
        await member.send(f'You have been banned from **{ctx.guild.name}** for **{reason}**')
        await member.ban(reason = f"Banned by {ctx.message.author} for "+reason)
        await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been banned.')
        cooldown.append(author)
        await asyncio.sleep(2 * 60 * 60)    #The argument is in seconds. 2hr = 7200s
        cooldown.remove(author)
    except:
        await ctx.send('Error. Please check you are typing the command correctly. `!ban @username (reason)`.')
```

However, if the user I am trying to ban has DM's disabled, the bot can't send the ban reason message, so therefore doesn't proceed to the next step, which is banning them, and returns the error message, which is Error. Please check you are typing the command correctly. !ban @username (reason)

Please can you rewrite the code to allow it to try to DM someone the reasoning before banning them, but if they have DM's disabled, it shall still ban them anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply moving the ban to be executed first (as it is a priority), then it will attempt to dm the user.

I also re-adjusted some parts of the code. It will now try to send a dm, if not, it will still ban but a message will be sent to the channel alerting a message was not sent to the banned user.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_role('Senior Moderator')
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
    author = ctx.author
    
    if author in cooldown:
        await ctx.send('Calm down! You\'ve already banned someone less than two hours ago.')
        return
    
    if member == None:
        await ctx.send('Please mention a member to ban!')
        return
    if reason == None:
        reason = 'breaking the rules.'
        
    await member.ban(reason = f"Banned by {ctx.message.author} for " + reason)
    
    try:
        await member.send(f'You have been banned from **{ctx.guild.name}** for **{reason}**')

    except:
        await ctx.send(f'A reason could not be sent to {ctx.message.author} as they had their dms off.')

    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been banned.')
    cooldown.append(author)
    await asyncio.sleep(2 * 60 * 60)
    cooldown.remove(author)
```

Answer (score 1):

I too noticed the same thing when I first made my bot ban command, I did the following to fix my ban command. First I tried a scenario where the bot could dm the user, if it can, then It will dm the user and then ban the user (Note: Do not ban the user before DMing the user as the bot can only DM the user when the user and the bot share a common server). However, I then made an Exception that if the bot couldn't dm the user, it will send a message in the channel the command was executed "Couldn't dm the user" then ban the user

```
try:
      await member.send(embed=embo)
      await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
except Exception:
      await ctx.send("Couldn't send dm to the user")
      await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
```

EDIT:
you can also opt for the following:

```
try:
      await member.send(embed=embo)
      await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
except discord.HTTPException:
      await ctx.send("Couldn't send dm to the user")
      await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
```

before I specified this, I encountered the following error.[image]

I fixed it, afterward, adding the exception case.

[image]